# Changing controller $scope vars dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

So. I have simple controller and service:

```
angular
    .module('field', [])
    .controller('FieldController', function(FieldService) {
         var vm = this;
         vm.name = FieldService.getName();
    })
    .service('FieldService', function() {
         var name = 'John'
         this.getName = function() {
             return name;
         };
         this.setName = function(newName) {
             name = newName;
         };
    })
    ;
```

Then i have some $interval in `anotherService`, that getting data every 1 second and calling `FieldService.setName`:

```
    .service('UpdateService', function($http, FieldService) {
        $interval(function() {
            $http.get('/somUrl')
                .then(function(response) {
                    FieldService.setName(response.name);
                });
        });
    })
```

But it won't change my HTML. 
If i switch from primitive to object in returning value `getName`, then it's working.

Is there another approach? I personally think, that this structure i created is bad, but can't understand how it should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is always pass-by-value, but when your variable is an object, the 'value' is actually a reference to the object.  So in your case, you are getting a reference to the object, not the value.  So when the object changes, that change isn't propagated like a primitive would be.

Your code seems a bit incorrect, too.  You are setting the value of `response.name` to `FieldService.setName`, which is actually a function.

If you want to use the getter/setter approach you have listed, then you could use events to let the controller know that name has changed.

```
.service('UpdateService', function($http, FieldService, $rootScope) {
        $interval(function() {
            $http.get('/somUrl')
                .then(function(response) {
                    FieldService.setName(response.name);
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('nameChanged', {
                        name : response.name
                    });
                });
        });
    })

  .controller('FieldController', function(FieldService, $scope) {
         var vm = this;
         vm.name = FieldService.getName();

         $scope.$on('nameChanged', function (evt, params) {
             vm.name = params.name;
         });
    })
```

Another way to accomplish this is to use a `$scope.$watch` on the service variable in the controller:

```
.controller('FieldController', function($scope, FieldService) {
         $scope.name = FieldService.getName();
         $scope.$watch(function () {
            return FieldService.getName();
         }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                $scope.name = newVal;
            }            
         });
    })
```

Comment: hm, thanks for the broadcast idea. i can $watch service variables from the controller?.. wow... could you provide example, please?

Comment: Updated my answer.  I realized you can leave your getter/setter approach as-is if you go with the $scope.$watch

Answer (score 0):

I would move my $interval function inside a controller and then just update a $scope attribute every second. Then Angular will take care of the rendering.. Or you must also use an $interval function in your controller which gets the service content (ie FieldService.getName) every second.

Comment: yes, this would work. the problem is, that inside `$interval` i could be anything. depends on response data it sets one param or another. or inside another controller/service.

Comment: If your service gets 'refreshed' every second, you should see to it that your controller also reads the 'refreshed' value from the service every second. If not you would have to generate som kind of $rootScope event and broadcast it, which I think would be a performance killer...

Comment: Maybe you need it inside another controller

Answer (score 0):

I would use it this way:

```
angular
    .module('field', [])
    .controller('FieldController', function($scope, FieldService) {
         $scope.name = function(){
            FieldService.getName();
         };
    })
    .service('FieldService', function() {
         var name = 'John'
         this.getName = function() {
             return name;
         };
         this.setName = function(newName) {
             name = newName;
         };
    });
```

Use name() in your html to see the update value.
And your other service:

```
.service('UpdateService', function($http, FieldService) {
        $interval(function() {
            $http.get('/somUrl')
                .then(function(response) {
                    FieldService.setName(response.name);
                });
        }, 1000);
    })
```

There are numerous ways in which you can achieve this. No way is the best way. Depends on person to person.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yep, this would work, because function is object, so passed by reference, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve that problem.

1) **Move the $interval to controller**.Then you will have a variable, which holds that data and you can bind it in view

2) **You can use AngularJs Events**.$rootScope will help you to send signal and catch it wherever you want.

If you want more info about this solutions, you can see it here: 
http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/bind-value-between-service-and-controller-directive.html